# generate key pair based on a string

Tags: c#, encryption

I need to create private\public key based on a string. (This string is unique machine-specific id generated at runtime. Public key will be shared, so all users could send the data to this machine.)

As far as I know, RSACryptoServiceProvider generates the key pair automatically. I need to generate the same pair each time I send the same string.

Any idea how to implement this in c#?

(added)
I'm not interested in creating a certificate and storing it locally, it doesn't suit in this case (because if you generate a cerificate in two different os installations on a computer, the keypairs will be different. I need machine-specific ID and keypair. I now how to generate ID, but I'm not sure yet how to generate keys base on it).

I'd like to use RSA, however, any asymmetric algorithm will be suitable.

Comment: I don't see any support for this. Normally you generate the keypair once and keep it locally. It doesn't sense for multiple users to have the same keypair. It is possible to export the keypair into a PKCS#12 file and push that around.

Comment: What happens when John's machine is given to Susan. Would these two people get the same key? That does not sound like a good practice.

Comment: Do you need RSA explicitely or any asymetric algorithm?

Comment: It's actually an interesting problem and I'm wondering if there's a cross-platform way to generate a high-quality RSA keypair based on fixed entropy.

Comment: The security of this protocol does not sound optimal. For example, if an attacker can guess the machine-specific id then he/she can derive the private key. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:
Use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) to derive two bitstrings. Interpret each part as one BigInteger, and find the next prime after it. These are your p,q from which you can construct your e,d,n used for RSA.
But this is probably a bad idea since I just invented it, and it's not based on established cryptography.

I'd rather generate a private key in a normal way on each computer, and store it. I think windows even offers a special way to store keys.

Comment: To generate p,q,e,d,n is about 120 lines of dense C/C++ code, if libraries for bignum and primes are given. The he's going to need to feed Windows the raw RSA values, something that involves messing with CryptoAPI blobs directly. Hardly a practical answer.

Comment: Is it that bad? I haven't implemented it myself, but from what I remember from my number theory class it isn't that hard.

Comment: I just looked at rsa_gen in OpenSSL and it's 220+ lines. Bignum, primes, and the RSA structure itself are all external.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It would be just a few lines with the BouncyCastle C# library, since it's BigInteger class has a NextProbablePrime() method.

Comment: OK, good idea. And are there any ideas how to calculate Modulus, Exponent etc manually in c#? They are necessary for RSAParameters structure, to pass generated keypair to the rsacryptoserviceprovider

Comment: I'd start with the `BigInteger` class(new in .net 4) and the wikipedia article on RSA.

Comment: One difficulty seems to be that some primes are weak, so you might want to read a bit more literature to make sure that your primes and private key are secure.

Answer (score 2):

There's no practical way to do this. Theoretically you could hack the RSA and RNG implementations of OpenSSL, and ensure that the only entropy the RSA keygenerator receives is your string. This way the keygen process would spit out one and only one RSA key per input string, no matter how many times you run it. However, your string will pretty much certainly not have enough entropy to make the generated key cryptographically useful. If that's not enough for you, there's also the problem of this process being highly dependent on the internals of the RSA keygen process, which may change between OpenSSL releases - which would cause a different key to be generated based on the same input.

Why can't you generate an RSA keypair and encrypt the private key with your string (using a symmetric algo), then store the encrypted blob locally? This way, instead of generating a key every time your app starts, it can decrypt the previously stored one, provided the string (machine fingerprint?) does not change.

Comment: For C# the external library of choice would be bouncycastle. It has its own BigInteger class modeled after Sun's Java BigInteger, as well as several other classes, including DotNetUtilities, that would make this implementable using CodeInChaos' ideas.