# RSA: how to generate RSA public and private keys based on a passphrase (.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, rsa

I'm working in .net environment (all versions) and using vb.net. I want to generate RSA public and private keys based on a passphrase.

My understanding of RSA algorithm only limited by using a class provided by the .net ie System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider Class. I know how to generate random RSA public/private keys and perform encryption/decryption.

But that .net class don't let us creating RSA public/private keys based on a passphrase.

Although I'm using vb.net, anyone with solutions in c#, c, c++ or any .net compatible language are welcomed to contribute as I can access the solution via p/invoke or dll reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to generate RSA keys based on a passphrase?

Comment: To do RSA encryption and decryption without first exchanging public key of both sender and receiver.

Comment: You do not want to use RSA for that. You need to use symmetrical encryption with password-based key derivation function (like PBKDF2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [generate key pair based on a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531033/generate-key-pair-based-on-a-string)

Comment: @CodeInChaos, sorry about that. I did search before posting my question and I missed that question. However, there was no solution to that question too.

Comment: The Answers to the Question linked by @CodeInChaos are the same as given below - Do not do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need RSA if you don't need public key encryption.

Use symmetrical encryption with password-based key derivation function (e.g. [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) with [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)). It will be faster and more secure.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should consider symmetric key encryption like AES, where a passphrase would make sense to derive a key from. You mentioned this is for internal use, do you really need RSA? If so perhaps what you want to do is protect the RSA private key file, which you could do by AES encrypting that file and using a passphrase for the key to that. You should always generate RSA public/private key pairs with software that's intended to do it.

Comment: +1 Symmetric key encryption is exactly what you get when you create Public keys based solely on a passphrase. Think about it, how do you plan to share the passphrase? Use this secure channel for a randomly created symmetric key instead.

Comment: @Stephan B, that passphrase also contains user private unique data, user's PC hardware and pre-installed software specific data.

Comment: @Stephan B: Suppose I turn the question around: What is wrong with regenerating the private key every time based on the passphrase as compared to protecting it with password-based symmetric encryption? (Other than the obvious in that it is much, much, slower). Imagine a device with no easy to use long term storage like an early smartphone for example.

Comment: @GregS: A device without storage, well that would be the only place to use this kind of setup. I still belive that symmetric keys will be a better fit: they need less entropy for equal security, compute faster and you don't need to invent your own cryptographic functions. Besides, which early smartphone without storage can generate a reasonable sized rsa key in due time? ; )

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you need roughly 2048 bits of randomness in order to *start* your primality tests (1024 bits on each potential-prime), and that your potential-primes may fail their primality tests, your passphrases would need to be *very long* to provide enough entropy to generate good keys.

Lets assume that there are roughly 94 keys on the keyboard that generate characters, and further assume that users will actually hit them *at random*. (Not a good assumption, but bear with me.)

That's `log(94)/log(2) == 6.55` bits of entropy per character. To get 2048 bits of entropy, you'll need to ask for a passphrase that is 313 characters long: `2048 / 6.55... == 312.45`.

How do you think your users will feel about being asked for a 300+ character passphrase? And remember, this is under the optimistic assumption that users will hit each of the 94 symbols at random; this seems vastly unlikely to me. I think 40-odd characters is going to be the *real* limit of people's creativity: 26 letters, 10 digits, and the punctuation keys that *don't* require shift. That'd be around 384 characters in your passphrase.

Please just stick to randomly-generated keys, where someone very clever is in charge of collecting the entropy to seed the pseudo-random-number generator.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The function that used to generate RSA public/private key based on a passphrase will be used internally by my class and not intended for end-users.

Comment: @sarnold, just to add, the questions of randomness and passphrase length can be safely ignored because my class can ensure any length required and the randomness can be ensured via another crypto-services provided by .net

Comment: I hope those keys are never used in the wild; [MITRE has a small list of programs that didn't properly generate their keys](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/330.html)

Comment: @Gens, then in what sense are those keys 'based on' the passphrase? I mean, if you want to ask the user to throw some entropy into the pool, that's all well and good, but doesn't seem like a particularly efficient way to acquire entropy.

Comment: @Gens, after seeing the other updates you've made, I think mgrobner's answer might suit your needs best.

Comment: @sarnold I don't think you need that much entropy. I think >100 bits of entropy should be enough. But them through an iterated hash function to slow down brute force and then seed a PRNG with it to generate 2000 pseudo random bits.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, it depends upon the value of the data protected with those keys; if it is for my diary, you're right, it should be fine. If it is for protecting financial data or other people's personal data, I'd still rather have more entropy. I've seen too many exploits from keys generated with insufficient random data to not point it out when I smell it. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Rsa keys are never based on a passphrase. You can only protect the rsa keys with a passphrase.